# Can you replace a substring from a regex match?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, substring

I am trying to find datatime stamps that have an incorrect timezone due to Daylight Savings Time (starting or ending). If the timezone is incorrect, I want to replace it with the correct timezone for those matches.

**e.g.** 2024-03-10T00:15:00-07:00 = 2024-03-10T00:15:00-08:00

I came up with the following regex and am able to find the culprits in the file using grep:

```
grep -E '~2024-03-10T[01]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}-07:00' <filename>
```

I am trying to do the substitution using **sed** and the regex I came up with, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

Here's what I currently have:

```
sed 's/\(~2024-03-10T[01]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\)-07:00~/\1-08:00~/g' filename
```

What am I missing? This command does not seem to make any substitutions. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `~` are not required, unless you really have those characters in your data file?  Cannot help much without a [mcve].

Comment: How do you know if a timestamp is daylight savings or not? Please provide complete input examples and expected output.

Comment: Since you are using curly braces in the pattern ie {2}, I would add the -E option to sed to enable extended regular expressions. Also if you want to change the file in-place(make backup) add the -i option aswell.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _does not seem to make any substitutions_? The command, as it is written, is not supposed to modify any file, but to write to stdout a copy of `filename`, with the substitutions applied. If you mean that what is written to stdout is identical to what is in `filename`, please say so explicitly.

Comment: @Nic3500 those characters are in the data file

Comment: @Bohemian I'm mostly concerned with timestamps between 12am and 2am of the starting/ending date for DST. I'm writing a bash script that takes that date as input

Comment: @Ishan Thank you for the tips. I will give that a shot. I don't need to make the change in place, but good to know

Comment: @user1934428 The latter is what is happening. When I write the stdout to a new file, the file is identical to the original file. I can see no substitutions were made for the 2 lines I altered for testing

Comment: In this case, it would have made more sense to post a simple `echo ...... | sed .....`, which demonstrates the problem. No need to mention your file, and we would then have a testcaes which can be reproduced by everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
$ cat filename
~2024-03-09T00:15:00-07:00~ some text
~2024-03-10T00:15:00-07:00~ some text
~2024-03-11T00:15:00-07:00~ some text
```

I tend to use `-E` to enable support for extended regexes and to simplify the capture group syntax.

This requires just a couple small changes to your current code:

```
sed -E 's/(~2024-03-10T[01]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})-07:00/\1-08:00/g' filename
    ^^    ^                                     ^
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable support for extended regexes
- `(` | `)` - no need to escape the parens (capture group delimiters)

This generates:

```
~2024-03-09T00:15:00-07:00~ some text
~2024-03-10T00:15:00-08:00~ some text
~2024-03-11T00:15:00-07:00~ some text
```

Comment: I should have looked at the man page a little better. Didn't realize sed also had -E for regex! Your changes solved my problem. Thanks!